# Centering a scaled ImageView

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm having trouble getting an ImageView that has been scaled down to center in my application. I've tried different scaleTypes (fitCenter, centerInside both give the correct dimensions but neither is centered), I've tried using RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout, I've tried adding empty Views with a weight of 0.25 to either side, I've tried setting layout_width to a specific width rather than using layout_weight...nothing appears to do the trick, the image is just left aligned. Thoughts?

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>The weighting is causing your problem here. You're specifying `weightSum="1"` on your `LinearLayout`, and then `layout_weight="0.5"` on your `ImageView`. This means that the image will only ever take up *half* the available space - the first half, for the layout you've got here. If you had set `weightSum="2"` and your image to `layout_weight="0.5"`, your image would only take up one quarter of the space (since the assigned weight is 1/4 of the total).</s>

You can fix this by either removing the `weightSum` and `layout_weight` attributes, or removing the `LinearLayout` altogether. I'd recommend removing the `LinearLayout` as there's no other children and it's not necessary;

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

I misunderstood. This works for me:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The weight is how I'm scaling the image. The intent here was for the image to take up 50% of the width. I tried putting empty views around the image, each with a weight of 0.25, to try to "fill" the surrounding space and force it into the middle, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I got the empty views working (see edit); I had to specify `0dp` height and width, and I had to make sure that my parent LinearLayout had `orientation="horizontal"`.

Comment: Ah! You're right, it was adding the 0dp height for the empty views that did the trick. I had 0dp for width and match_parent for height. Thanks!